# angular5 reactive forms async validators not called

Tags: validation, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms

I`ve made my custom validators which works well now I add a async validation but it seems like it is not called. The first step what my validator do (just for test)is that it logs something but never logs it. If i put my async validator to array of sync validators it works but when I move it to async array it doesnt works.
form definiton:

```
 form = new FormGroup({
email: new FormControl('',[
  Validators.required
],[
  MemberValidators.isEmailUnique
]),
firstName: new FormControl('',[
  Validators.required,
  MemberValidators.cannotContainSpace
]),. . . . .
```

and the async Validator

```
   static isEmailUnique(c: AbstractControl): Promise<ValidationErrors> | null{
    console.log('isEmail unique');
    let users=['adam','jarda'];
    let email=c.value;
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
        setTimeout(() =>{
        if (users.indexOf(email)>0){
            resolve({isEmailUnique: true});
            console.log('Email not unique');
        }
        else 
            resolve(null);
        },1000);
        });
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: changed return value of  isEmailUnique to  Promise<ValidationErrors | null> but this didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I`ve rebuild it with FormBuilder and works fine. Problem was probably somewhere in syntax.

```
this.form=fb.group({
  firstName: ['', Validators.minLength(2)],
  lastName: ['', Validators.minLength(2)],
  email: ['', [Validators.email, Validators.required],[MemberValidators.isEmailUnique]],
  notified: ['', Validators.required],
  locale: ['',],
  password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)],
  passwordConfirm: ['', Validators.required],
},{validator:[ MemberValidators.passwordNotMatches]}
```

)